# Generate Password protected pdf rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wicked-pdf

I am using wicked PDF for my PDF generation. Now I am looking something to Prevent someone to copy the data from my pdf .When anyone tries to copy some data it should ask for password or the person should not be able to copy the data from PDF .I have look so much on Internet but didn't got any solution so far .Can any one help me with this problem

Comment: I also have the same problem but was not able to find any solution :(

Answer (score 5):

You can use `prawn` for this: https://github.com/cortiz/prawn-rails

```
pdf = Prawn::Document.new

pdf.encrypt_document(
  user_password: 'foo', 
  owner_password: 'bar',
  permissions: { 
    print_document: false,
    modify_contents: false,
    copy_contents: false,
    modify_annotations: false 
  }
)
```

Check out http://prawnpdf.org/manual.pdf for more description and permissions.

And look through this example: http://code.runnable.com/Uo6huSS6Ut8nAAFm/how-to-password-protect-pdfs-with-prawn-for-ruby-on-rails

Comment: I don't want to use prawn I need to manage with wicked pdf only .Is there any option ?

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari perhaps, but, unfortunately, I can't help you with that, because I haven't found any.